# Viewing deleted files in Vault

Tags: sourcegear-vault

Is there a way to view the contents and history of deleted files in the SourceGear Vault Client?  The only way I have found is to *undelete* the file, view the file, and then *delete* the file again.

I'm currently using Vault 4.1.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To view the contents of a deleted file, you can `Get` an old version of the folder that contained the deleted file (before it was deleted) into an alternative directory. That will put a copy of the deleted file in that directory for you to examine.

As far as I know, there is no way to look at the history of a deleted file unless you undelete it.